# How to create a dictionary through looping a 2D list?

Tags: python, list

just wondering if there is a way to convert a 2D list into a dictionary.

In my results list I have something like

```
[(15000001, datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 26, 12, 58, 10)), (15000002, datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 26, 12, 58, 11))]
```

And I am try to find a way to loop it to get

```
{'StudentID': results[row][0] ,'ClassAttended': results[row][1]}
```

The psudocode will be like

```
for row in results:
    for item in row:
        DO THIS {'StudentID': results[row][0] ,'ClassAttended': results[row][1]}
```

Which will print out something like

```
{'StudentID' : '15000001', 'ClassAttended': '2018-2-26 12:58:10'}
```

Comment: Where is your coding attempt?  You seem to be clear on how to access individual elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, use `dict`, `zip`, and a list comprehension.

```
result = [ dict(zip(["StudentID", "ClassAttended"], row)) for row in inputlist]
```

or more directly:

```
result = [ {"StudentID": student, "ClassAttended": class}
         for (student, class) in inputlist]
```

---

Note that your code is nearly correct, and only needs to be accumulated.

```
accumulator = []
for row in inputlist:
    d = {"StudentID": row[0],
         "ClassAttended": row[1]}
    accumulator.append(d)
```

Comment: This results works in a way! But one of the main reason i want it in a loop is that I am trying to convert the datetime.datetime too using datetime.fromtimestamp(int(result[1][x])).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'). How can I do this using your method.

Comment: @computer you can do whatever you like in the list comprehension. I don't know what `x` is in your sample code in the comment, but if `class` is the datetime, then `[ {..., "ClassAttended": class.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')} for ...]` should give you your result. Also note my adaptation of your code below the rule.

Comment: Just saw the code below the rule and tested out with the implementation and it is now working. Thank you for your clarification!